# Scheduled Job Is Not Running

Tags: apex, batch, callout, scheduled

I have written a REST API request that passes the response body to a class to deserialize it into a wrapper class. That rapper class then passes a list of records into a batch class incrementally so that I avoid DML limit errors. It works as expected when run from the Developer Console. I then created a schedulable class to call the API every 15 mins. However, I can see that it's not running and I'm wondering if there is a limitation to prevent a scheduled job from executing a batch job? Can anyone help please? Here is my code:

```
    global with sharing class ScheduleCin7ProductSync implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        FetchCin7Products products = New FetchCin7Products();
        products.MakeCallout();
    }
}
```

---

```
  public with sharing class FetchCin7Products {
    // Method to perform callouts
    public void MakeCallout(){

        // define a response to caller
        String outcomeMsg;
        
        // define basic information for later, store these in a protected custom setting
        Cin7_API_Details__c cin7 = [SELECT Id, Last_Product_Poll__c, API_Endpoint__c,
                                    Username__c, Key__c FROM Cin7_API_Details__c LIMIT 1];

        String dt = String.valueOf(cin7.Last_Product_Poll__c.dateGmt())+'T'+String.valueOf(cin7.Last_Product_Poll__c.timeGmt());
        string endpoint = cin7.API_Endpoint__c + 'products?where=modifieddate>=\'' + dt + '\'';
        string username = cin7.Username__c; 
        string password = cin7.Key__c;
        string method = 'GET';
        
        // check to ensure a callout can be performed using the Limits class. 
        // This is 100 callouts per execution as of Spring 16 release
        if (Limits.getCallouts() >= Limits.getLimitCallouts()) {
            outcomeMsg = 'Maximum number of callouts has been reached.';
            
        // check for credentials error
        } else if (endpoint == null || username == null || password == null) {
            outcomeMsg = 'Please verify your API Credentials';
            
        // configure and perform the callout
        } else {
            
            endpoint = endpoint;
            // define transaction variables
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            Http h = new Http();
            
            // Configure the request
            req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
            req.setMethod(method);
            req.setTimeout(120000);
            
            // Add basic authentication to header
            // Create blob of user:pass
            Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
            // Base 64 Encode the blob and prepend "Basic "
            String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
            // Add the basic auth string to the Request Header
            req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);            

            // Configure standard headers
            req.setHeader('Accept', '*/*');
            // This tells the API that we are sending and receiving the data as a JSON object 
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            // Attempt the callout - create return error on exception
            try {
                
                // Perform callout and set response
                res = h.send(req);

                System.debug('Status:' + res.getStatusCode());
                System.debug('Body:' + res.getBody());

                // check response 
                if ((res.getStatusCode() == 200 || res.getStatusCode() == 201) && res.getBody() != '[]') {
            
                // Deserialize the response untyped
                Cin7ProductParser.parseCin7Product(res.getBody());

                } else {
                // callout failed
                    outcomeMsg = 'Error: Callout failed. Please review the debug log for additional details.';
                }

            } catch (exception e) {
                // Unexpected exceptions will be caught here, like a deserialization error.
                outcomeMsg = 'Error: An exception has been encountered while calling out to Integration:  ' + e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
   public with sharing class Cin7ProductParser {

    public static void parseCin7Product(String body) {

        List<ProductWrapper> data = ProductWrapper.parse(body);

        BatchProductsParser batch = New BatchProductsParser(data);
        Id batchProcessId = Database.executeBatch(batch, 20);
    }
}
```

---

```
  public with sharing class BatchProductsParser implements Database.Batchable<ProductWrapper>{

    public List<ProductWrapper> wrapper = New List<ProductWrapper>();

    public BatchProductsParser(List<ProductWrapper> wrap) {
        wrapper = wrap;
    }

    public Iterable<ProductWrapper> start(Database.BatchableContext context){
        return wrapper;
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<ProductWrapper> scope) {

        List<Product2> updatedProducts = New List<Product2>();
        List<PricebookEntry> updatedPriceBookEntries = New List<PricebookEntry>();
        List<PricebookEntry> stdPriceBookEntries = New List<PricebookEntry>();
        Map<Id, Pricebook2> priceBooks = New Map<Id, Pricebook2>([SELECT Id, Cin7_Price_Tier__c FROM PriceBook2 WHERE IsActive = true]);


        Map<String, String> priceTierToPriceBook = New Map<String, String>();
        for(PriceBook2 pb :priceBooks.values()) {
            priceTierToPriceBook.put(pb.Cin7_Price_Tier__c, pb.Id);
        }
 
        Schema.SObjectField key = Pricebookentry.Cin7_Key__c;

        for(ProductWrapper wrap :scope) {
            if(wrap.channels.contains('Salesforce')) {
                for(ProductWrapper.productOptions option :wrap.productOptions) {
                    updatedProducts.add(
                        //Associate each product via transient
                        option.record = New Product2(
                            Cin7Id__c = option.id,
                            Modified__c = Datetime.valueOf(option.modifiedDate.replace('T',' ')),
                            Name = wrap.name + ' - ' + option.option1,
                            ProductCode = option.productOptionCode,
                            Cin7_Status__c = option.status,
                            Family = wrap.category,
                            IsActive = true,
                            Cin7InStock__c = option.stockAvailable,
                            Cin7_Stock_On_Hand__c = option.stockOnHand,
                            Cin_7_Stock_Available__c = option.stockAvailable,
                            Description = wrap.description,
                            Option_1__c = wrap.optionLabel1,
                            Option_2__c = wrap.optionLabel2,
                            Option_3__c = wrap.optionLabel3,
                            Value1__c = option.option1,
                            Value2__c = option.option2,
                            Value3__c = option.option3
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        upsert updatedProducts Cin7Id__c;

        //Create Price Book Entries
        for(ProductWrapper wrapper :scope) {
            if(wrapper.channels.contains('Salesforce')) {
                for(ProductWrapper.productOptions po :wrapper.productOptions) {

                    stdPriceBookEntries.add(
                        New PricebookEntry(
                            Pricebook2Id = priceTierToPriceBook.get('Standard Price'),
                            Product2Id = po.record.Id,
                            UnitPrice = po.priceColumns.retailAUD,
                            Cin7_Key__c = 'Standard Price' + po.id,
                            IsActive = true,
                            UseStandardPrice = false
                        )
                    );

                    Map<String, Double> priceMap = New Map<String, Double>();
                    priceMap.put('retailAUD', po.priceColumns.retailAUD);
                    priceMap.put('amazonAUD', po.priceColumns.amazonAUD);
                    priceMap.put('5MRetaildiscounAUD', po.priceColumns.x5MRetaildiscounAUD);
                    priceMap.put('10MRetailDiscouAUD', po.priceColumns.x10MRetailDiscouAUD);
                    priceMap.put('councilAUD', po.priceColumns.councilAUD);
                    priceMap.put('neilsensAUD', po.priceColumns.neilsensAUD);
                    priceMap.put('jjRichardsAUD', po.priceColumns.jjRichardsAUD);
                    priceMap.put('rpgaud', po.priceColumns.rpgaud);
                    priceMap.put('10PWholesaleAUD', po.priceColumns.x10PWholesaleAUD);
                    priceMap.put('carlotAUD', po.priceColumns.carlotAUD);
                    priceMap.put('everhardAUD', po.priceColumns.everhardAUD);
                    priceMap.put('jawsAUD', po.priceColumns.jawsAUD);
                    priceMap.put('vipaud', po.priceColumns.vipaud);
                    priceMap.put('acsaud', po.priceColumns.acsaud);
                    priceMap.put('turosiAUD', po.priceColumns.turosiAUD);
                    priceMap.put('alsaud', po.priceColumns.alsaud);
                    priceMap.put('25PCostAUD', po.priceColumns.x25PCostAUD);
                    priceMap.put('ebayAUD', po.priceColumns.ebayAUD);
                    priceMap.put('wholesalenAUD', po.priceColumns.wholesalenAUD);
                    priceMap.put('costAUD', po.priceColumns.costAUD);
                    priceMap.put('specialPrice', po.priceColumns.specialPrice);
                        
                    for(String tier :priceMap.KeySet()) {
                        updatedPriceBookEntries.add(
                            New PricebookEntry(
                                Pricebook2Id = priceTierToPriceBook.get(tier),
                                Product2Id = po.record.Id,
                                UnitPrice = priceMap.get(tier),
                                Cin7_Key__c = tier + po.id,
                                IsActive = true
                            )
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Update or set the Standard Price
        List<Database.upsertResult> results = Database.upsert(stdPriceBookEntries, key, false);
        //Update or set custom prices
        List<Database.upsertResult> upsertResults = Database.upsert(updatedPriceBookEntries, key, false);
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        Cin7_API_Details__c cin7 = [SELECT Id, Last_Product_Poll__c, API_Endpoint__c,
                                    Username__c, Key__c FROM Cin7_API_Details__c LIMIT 1];

        cin7.Last_Product_Poll__c = Datetime.now();
        update cin7;
    }
}
```

Comment: There most certainly is no blocker preventing Schedulable from running Batchable. Are you sure that it's not running? Where did you look to confirm that? If you are inspecting your `Product2` table to draw this conclusion, you should instead look at the `Apex Jobs` tab and search for your classes. They may well be running with errors.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson, so I found this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2010/02/spring-10-saw-the-general-availability-of-one-of-my-favorite-new-features-of-the-platform-the-apex-schedulerwith-the-apex-s.html
Which suggested that my callout needs to be a future method. That allowed the callout to run but I then received the following error:
apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method.